# how do I generate list items whose (text) content correspond to another list's list item ID attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes, each

I have a hard-coded list, each list item of which has an ID. I want to have jQuery generate list items in another list, and set as their text content the ID attribute values of each of the hard-coded list’s items:

i.e. hard-coded list:

```
<ul class="gallery"> 
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery-generated list:

```
<ul class="galleryNav"> 
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have jQ getting the number of gallery items ...

```
var ListItemCount = $('ul.gallery').children().size('li');
```

... here’s the trouble: how do I get jQuery to get each of the list items’ IDs as it generates the nav list (below) ?

```
var ListItemIndex = $('ul.pofo li').attr('id');
var listItem = '<li>Slide #' + ListItemIndex + ' of ' + $('ul.gallery li').length + ' list items!</li>';
```

this is generating the nav list however the content in each is the same because of my blindspot with regard to var ListItemIndex

```
$("ul.gallery li").each(function (i) {
    i = i+1;
    $('ul.galleryNav').append(listItem);
});
```

The results of the above code generates the list but all the list items’ content is the same, ‘Slide #1 of 3 items’.

Many thanks in advance!

svs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbEcV/)**. The code:

```
var listItemCount = $('.gallery').children().size('li');

$('.gallery li').each(function() {
    $('.galleryNav').append(
        '<li>Slide #' + $(this).attr('id') + ' of ' 
             + listItemCount + ' list items!</li>');
});
```

Your code had the basics right, you just need to move the appending to the `each` function that will execute for each list item. The item can then be accessed with `$(this)`.

Comment: Thanks Nikola! I tried this one first as it seemed most like the direction I was in. At first I had no list, not sure what I had breaking it, but with a little tweaking I now have the results I wanted with this:

Comment: var listItemCount = $('ul.sGallery').children().size('li');
 $('ul.sGallery li').each(function() {
  var listItem = '<li><a href="#"><span>#' + $(this).attr('id') + '</span> of ' + listItemCount + '</a></li>';
  $('ul.sGalleryNav').append(listItem);

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var newUl = document.createElement('ul'); // It's marginally faster to create elements without jQuery.
newUl.id = 'galleryNav'; // setting the id of the element.
var count = $('.gallery li').length; // retrieving the number of list items
$('body').append(newUl); // appending the created <ul> to the body

$('.gallery li').each(
    function(i){ // iterating through each of the li eleents of the .gallery list
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // creating a new list-element
        // using the i variable returned by the each() function, adding 1 to counter JavaScript's zero-based numbering
        // and appending that created element to the galleryNav
        $(li).text('Slide ' + (i+1) + ' of ' + count).appendTo('#galleryNav');
    }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A4Sh6/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: if you care about fast, why dont you create a string in the each loop and append it after the list is created? using the text method and the appendTo for each element can be slow, if there are lots of elements

Comment: It's not so much I care about 'fast,' I just prefer to use the easiest means to accomplish a task. For me it's easier to use the native JavaScript methods and then for the more awkward tasks use the jQuery methods, which is why I used `text()`, plus the question seemed to revolve around how to use `each()` to find the index of an element. I just felt that this approach better answered that question.

Comment: ok thats worth a +1 for me ;) I preferred the fast version. So now he hase the choice.

Comment: Thanks David & Meo. Yup, I have a choice, 'cause I have both your and Nikola's solutions working ;) - thanks for the lesson. I hear you re: native js vs. jQ, but in my case it's the other way 'round as I'm more comfortable with jQ. Anyway, for anyone else reading this, this is also a great solution, and your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i would not append it in the loop, but constructing a string and append it when its finished. its much faster then append it for each li in the gallery.

```
var newList = "<ul class='galleryNav'>"; //starting the list

$(".gallery li").each(function(i){ //looping your gallery elements
    newList += "<li>Slide" + this.id || i + "</li>"; //extending the list
});

$("body").append( newList += "</ul>" );  //appending the list to the body or whatever
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/yKgSf/​

or the fancy version (because constructing long strings with JS can be slow)

```
var newList = []; // creating a empty array

$(".gallery li").each(function(i){ //looping your gallery list
    newList.push("<li>Slide" + this.id || i + "</li>"); //extending the array
});

$("body").append( "<ul class='galleryNav'>" + newList.join("") + "</ul>" ); //joining the array and append it to the body
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/yKgSf/2/

PS: Having only a number as ID is not W3C valid in HTML4. Thats why i choose to use the index alternatively when there is no ID on the element

Comment: I rather like this version. =) +1 ...although "if you care about fast" why are you using `$(this)[0].id` as opposed to `this.id` in your `each()`? =b

Comment: very very good point i correct this. its totally inefficient :P (and a little stupid)

Comment: Cheers again Meo & David. As to the numerical IDs: as a standards html/css guy, I concur. I've just been hacking at this portfolio  notion so I threw in some numerical IDs; they will soon be prefixed semantically, and if you listen carefully you can hear me wrestling with .split() in my listItem variable ;)